# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't render on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I've been using AngularJS in conjunction with Cordova, and recently some strange events have been happening. On random occasions when the page first loads the ng-repeat will not render out the list, however, the data is in local WebSQL and the query is bringing back the data everytime as I tell JavaScript to console.log the data everytime.

WebSQL becomes populated on login, the login in function will send a request to an API, gather some data and then store it. Once the page hasn't loaded the data normally I would navigate to another page and then back. At this point the list would of appeared. The technologies I am using is IonicFramework (Downloaded the latest stable from yesterday), Cordova and finally RequireJS.

**JavaScript Controller**

```
// Run the query to gather the applications which are locally stored within the database
$scope.appData = ApplicationService.get_applications();
```

**ApplicationService**

```
/*global define, console */

define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    var factory = function (ConfigurationService, DatabaseService) {

        return {

            // GET ALL APPLICATIONS SAVED IN SQLITE
            get_applications: function () {
                var i = 0, data = [];
                DatabaseService.raw().query('SELECT * FROM applications', function (tx, res) {
                    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                        for (i; i < res.rows.length; i += 1) {
                            data[i] = {
                                'first_name': res.rows.item(i).first_name,
                                'last_name': res.rows.item(i).last_name,
                                'name': res.rows.item(i).name,
                                'application_id': res.rows.item(i).application_id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                return data;
            },


        };

    };

    factory.$inject = ['ConfigurationService', 'DatabaseService'];
    return factory;
});
```

**View File**

```
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-repeat="data in appData">
                    <a ng-click="highlight({{ data.application_id }})" id="{{ data.application_id }}" class="" title="{{ data.name }}">
                        <h2>{{ data.first_name }} {{ data.last_name }} <p>{{ data.name }}</p></h2>
                    </a>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
```

Some help would be gratefully appreciated as this is considered a major bug within my application.

Comment: is websql natively supported ? because if you are using websql plugin you may need to use scope.apply to reflect the changes immediately in view as in this case your code would be executing outside angular context.

Comment: @Amitesh Sorry for the long reply, I've been out the office. It's natively supported, we are using Google Chrome to emulate the application. When the mobile app is compiled to the device (using Cordova) the same thing happens again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same thing using PhoneGap and AngularJS.

I used an angular timer at 150ms which seemed to be enough time to read the database and then forced a refresh on Angular using $scope.$apply(). I've heard using $apply isn't good practise but I couldn't get anything else to work.

Use this line:

```
$timeout(function(){ $scope.$apply(); }, 150);
```

My application reads a WebSQL db on load and the contents is displayed in an ngRepeat.

```
    shoppingListApp.controller('BaseController',
    function BaseController($scope, OfflineStorageService, $timeout){

        //fields
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $scope.shoppingList = [];

        //methods
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $scope.init = function () {
            var tempShoppingList = OfflineStorageService.load($scope.tableName);

            if(tempShoppingList) {
                $scope.shoppingList = tempShoppingList;
                $timeout(function(){ $scope.$apply(); }, 150);
            }
        };

        $scope.init();
    }
```